# selecting only those li having ULs

Tags: jquery, zepto

I am trying to select all those `li` under a `div` having className `ui-menu` like having `UL` as their child element.

Comment: Can you show us some code that you have tried?

Comment: Who has the `.ui-menu` class: the `<div>` or the `<li>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [:has](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

```
$('div.ui-menu li:has(ul)')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [**:has()**](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector.

In case you meant that the `div` is the one to have the `.ui-menu` class use this:

`$('div.ui-menu li:has(ul)')`

In case you meant that the `li` is the one to have the `.ui-menu` class use this:

`$('div li.ui-menu:has(ul)')`